# Visual studio does not include the prerequisites that I specify

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, prerequisites, setup-wizard

I have a visual studio solution that consists of a wpf application (project1) and a setup project. I need this prerequisite:
[image]

### when I deploy Project1 by itself everything works fine:

[image]

that is the prerequisite that I told visual studio to include...

But I want to create a Setup Wizard Project and Include my Project1 along with the extra files that I want to deploy. When I create that project, complile, recomplie with the release options selected and also the debug option selected in order to make sure I am including my project build take a look how that behaves:

** Removed... Take a look at the edit. I explain everything with more detail in there**

---

---

---

> ```
>                                 EDIT
> ```

---

---

---

### I will show the steps that I perform

> Steps:

**Step 1)**

> Create console application include the prerequisites that I want to include

[image]

**Step 2)**

> Set the target framework to .NET Framework 4

[image]

**Step 3)**

> Set this changes in the publish tab on properties:

[image]

**and**

[image]

**Setp 4)**

> Publish this solution without a a setup wizard.

[image]

**Setp 5)**

> Launch the setup file that was just created on a different clean machine

[image]

**Step 6)**

> Cancel the installation let's try to do the same thing with a setup project

[image]

**Step 7)**

> Once setup1 project is created let's add Console application to the project output

[image]

**Step 8)**

> Now my setup1 project looks like:

[image]

**Step 9)**

> Now I build that project and export it to my other computer where I want to test the installation

[image]

### Note that when I launch Setup1.exe It want's to install Windows Installer 3.1!!!! Why????

**Step 10)**

> Ok whatever right.. Let's continue with the installaction let's accept and continue...

[image]

### Now it want to install the client version and not the full!!! why?

**Step 11)**

> Now windows download the installer (remember that I told visual studio in setting that I did not wanted to download anything...)

**Step 12)**

> Setup1.exe now installs the client version of .net framework

[image]

**Step 13-14)**

> Setup1.exe prompts me to install my console application I click next since the program is so small I did not had time to take a screen shot but now the installation is complete

[image]

---

> Installation is now done

---

### Why did the prerequisites that I specified for console application not included!?  Why everything works if I don't include a Setup project? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both Debug and Release are setup to behave the same.

There isn't any sort of cache, if its trying to install Windows Installer 3.1 it is because of human error.

Comment: How do I setup debug or release to behave a certain way?

Comment: You don't know how to change the Setup project's Release and Debug packages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the application on the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, you need to change the application project properties and set `Target framework` to `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` (which is actually the default value in VS2010):

[image]

If you create a SETUP project in your solution, you need to define the prerequisites in the SETUP project and NOT IN the project `Publish tab` which publishes the app using `ClickOnce` mechanism.

So, the prerequisites defined in the Publish tab doesn't have anything to do with the setup project.

To add the prerequisites you need in the SETUP project, you should right click on the setup project, select properties and then prerequisites: [image: setup properties]